# How to use break in if (Command)

Tags: php

I am using ***$i*** string for limit in foreach loop.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($string as $menu){
   $i++;
   if($i == 6){
   break;
   }
   $menu_name = $menu['name'];
   $menu_style = $menu['style'];

   // i want to show total 5 menu names.


   if($menu_style == 'magazine'){
   // i have 5+ menus names (magazine style)
   // butt here i want to show just one last magazine 
   echo $menu_name;
   }

   if($menu_style == 'normal'){
   // i have 5+ names menus (normal style)
   // butt here i want to show  4 last normal style 
   echo $menu_name.'<br>';
   }

}
```

I can't want to use LIMIT in SQL query.

> And tell me when i use *if($i == 5){ break; }* then code display just 4
>   menu name

Tell me how is display menu name as my required.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?  If you want to iterate 5 times, then use `if ($i == 6)`, which you're already doing in the code posted.  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to select if($menu_style == 'magazine') so display name only one.

Comment: and if($menu_style == 'normal') so display name 4 name.

Comment: That doesn't really clarify the problem.  Those `if` statements will do exactly what they're expected to do.  What isn't working?  What is the value of `$menu_style`?  How is the code behaving differently from what you expect?  Please describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
$i = 0;

foreach($string as $menu){
   $i++;
   if($i == 6){
   break;
   }
   $menu_name = $menu['name'];
   $menu_style = $menu['style'];

   // i want to show total 5 menu names.


   if($menu_style == 'magazine' && $i <= 5){
   // i have 5+ menus names (magazine style)
   // butt here i want to show just one last magazine 
       echo $menu_name;
   } else if($menu_style == 'normal' && $i <= 4){
   // i have 5+ names menus (normal style)
   // butt here i want to show  4 last normal style 
        echo $menu_name.'<br>';
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Dear.. you have solved my problem